# PHP: can't upload files to google cloud storage! (error 400)

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I've written a short php script in order to upload a local file to my Google cloud storage bucket, using PHP client library (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).
I can authenticate, I can list the remote content, but simply I can't upload anything, since I obtain an error 400 ("Uploads must be sent to the upload URL").

This is my full script, that I modified following from some tutorial found online:

```
<?php
require_once "/var/www/local/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php"; // API Google library

define('GAPI_CLIENT_ID', 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
define('GAPI_EMAIL_ADDRESS', 'YYY@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
define('GAPI_API_KEY', 'xxxmyapikeyxxx');
define('GAPI_PROJECT_ID', 'projectid');

// certificate file
define('KEY_FILE_LOCATION', '/var/www/local/passphrase.p12');

// bucket name
$bucket = "mybucketname"
// remote file name
$file_name = "test.mp3";
// file to upload
$local_file = "/var/www/local/test.mp3";

$google_cert = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
 GAPI_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
 array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
 file_get_contents(KEY_FILE_LOCATION)
);

$google_client = new Google_Client();
$google_client->setAssertionCredentials($google_cert);
$google_client->setDeveloperKey(GAPI_API_KEY);

$service = new Google_Service_Storage($google_client);

$obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$obj->setName($file_name);
$obj->setContentType('media');
$obj->setSize(filesize($local_file));

$dataFILE['data']=file_get_contents($local_file);
$dataFILE['uploadType']="media";

$service->objects->insert(
 $bucket,
 $obj,
 $dataFILE
);

?>
```

What's wrong with it??

Comment: Ok, I fixed it!

My script was ok... there was a bug in the google-api-php library that generated a "malformed url" for upload, adding a double slash.
(for example: https://www.googleapis.com//upload instead of https://www.googleapis.com/upload).

Last release (3 days ago!) fixed the problem!

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the same problem. Updating the lib fixed it.